# vba excel connections query tables delete

Tags: excel, connection, vba

in a bigger Excel application, (25 sheets, 50 command-buttons, 5000 lines of code, 18 userforms ... size 12 MB) ... we load tables from a server as txt files and reconvert these txt_files to excel data with the standard procedure.
By macro we delete all querytables and connections after the downloads.

Everything worked perfect and quick, but the main sheet is getting slower and slower now.
Even opening the Workbook takes more and more time, while the size remains constant.

Somehow I have the feeling, there are remainings of the data transfer from the txt_files which are not deleted with:

#

```
Dim ws As Worksheet   
Dim qt As QueryTable   
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets   
For Each qt In ws.QueryTables   
qt.Delete   
Next qt   
Next ws   

If ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0 Then   
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count   
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete   
Next i 
EndIf
```

#

There are no formulas in the workbook. 
The slowing down persists, even selecting all cells of the main_sheet + clear ... I suppose all cells are empty after that command...

In the other 24 Sheets there are no speed_problems (even filtering a List 850.000 x 33)

Any idea how to check what is slowing down the Workbook in the main_sheet?
Are there more powerful 'cleanup'commands then deleting querytables and connections?
Are there any methods to log what is excel doing, while it does not return the command?

Comment: I read somewhere that starting with Excel 2007, you have to deal with QueryTable within each ActiveSheet.ListObjects

Comment: If you are trying to clear the main_sheet, you should select all and on your keyboard press (Control & -) that's Control key and while holding it down press the minus key on your number pad, this should delete all the cells, and not just clear the contents, therefore releasing some memory...

Answer (score 1):

This may not be related at all, apologies, but I found the problem for me was not the number of connections, but the number of *parameters in each connection*.

I found the "culprit" were obsolete/excessive Parameter objects left behind in the Query Tables themselves. Some of my Queries had around 15 parameters, when the SQL only needed one!

Excel does not have an interface that I know of, to **delete** Parameters once they've been created against a `QueryTable`. This can happen when you're manually adjusting the SQL code directly in Excel, and saving it with new or extra parameters using the '?' character, per parameter. When you finally settle down on one parameter, all the other parameters are still left behind. I could not find a way to clear/delete them.

If you ...

> go to Excel -> File Open your workbook -> Stop all macros (if any) ->
>   Click Data -> Queries & Connections to open up all your Queries, etc
>   -> Double-click a Query or Connection and check the Definitions tab and click Parameters..., you may see a huge list of parameters that do
>   the same thing as the first parameter.

This can slow Excel exponentially, because for every Query call by Excel to refresh the worksheet/table, it is running that query again, and again 'n' times.

Since Excel does not have a proper interface to manage Parameters, I've had to delete them all using this code and create only ONE parameter per Query.

```
For Each Cn In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        Cn.Parameters.Delete
Next Cn
```

I could not find a way to delete only one or a few parameters, such as `Cn.Parameter(ndx).Delete`. There is no such method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete
```

Check also in Formula / Named Ranges as with every ListObject table new Named Range is added.

```
Sub DeleteAllNamedRanges()
Dim NR As Name
For Each NR In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    NR.Delete
Next
End Sub
```